# Get attribute from class instance without passing Self

Tags: python, python-3.x, listener, pynput

```py
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button

class ClickListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ClickTimes = 0
        self.CurrentClick = 0
        self.ClickPositions = []

    def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed and button == Button.middle:
            ClickPositions.append((x,y))
            self.CurrentClick += 1
            if self.ClickTimes <= self.CurrentClick:
                return Falses

    def getClicks(self, nr):
        self.ClickPositions = []
        self.CurrentClick = 0
        self.ClickTimes = nr
        with Listener(on_click = ClickListener.on_click) as listener:
            listener.join()
        return self.ClickPositions
```

On function 'on_click' how can I have access to the self atributes since is the event that calls the functions? It seems I cannot pass the self object to the event.

Edit1.:

```
class ClickListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ClickTimes = 0
        self.CurrentClick = 0
        self.ClickPositions = []

    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed and button == Button.middle:
            self.ClickPositions.append((x,y))
            self.CurrentClick += 1
            if self.ClickTimes <= self.CurrentClick:
                return Falses

    def getClicks(self, nr):
        self.ClickPositions = []
        self.CurrentClick = 0
        self.ClickTimes = nr
        with Listener(on_click = self.on_click) as listener:
            listener.join()
        return self.ClickPositions
```

in this case it says that one required argument is missing, the 'pressed' one.

Comment: Why are you not defining your method as you should, with `self` as the first parameter? Then you simply pass `self.on_click` as your callback and it will be a bound method instead of the plain function.

Comment: I tried it, but when I put ```self``` as the first param of on_click the listener callback use the self param as the x, the x as y and on, at the end it says that 'pressed' is not defined

Comment: No, it does not, if you pass `self.on_click` with the method properly defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this.

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button

class ClickListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ClickTimes = 0
        self.CurrentClick = 0
        self.ClickPositions = []

    @classmethod
    def on_click(cls, x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed and button == Button.middle:
            cls.ClickPositions.append((x,y))
            cls.CurrentClick += 1
            if cls.ClickTimes <= cls.CurrentClick:
                return Falses

    @classmethod
    def getClicks(cls, nr):
       cls.ClickPositions = []
       cls.CurrentClick = 0
       cls.ClickTimes = nr
       with Listener(on_click = cls.on_click) as listener:
            listener.join()
       return cls.ClickPositions
```

Comment: Awesome! Maybe what I was missing whas the ```@classmethod```, anyway it worked! Thanks!

Comment: happy coding :)